# Haskell- Running monad states

Tags: haskell, monads, states

I am stuck trying to get this function:

```
runArrayState :: Array arr => ArrayState arr e a -> arr e -> (a, arr e)
```

to run the ArrayState action let's call it **act** with array **arr**  and get result and return the result **res** and original array **arr'** as a pair (res,arr').

ArrayState is defined as

```
data ArrayState arr e a = MkArrayState (arr e -> (a, arr e))
```

I thought it would be:

```
runArrayState act arr = ((act arr), arr)
```

or

```
runArrayState MkArrayState (\ arr -> (res, arr)) arr' = (res, arr')
```

but it all fails. Any ideas?

Comment: `ArrayState` only has one constructor with one argument.  In almost every such situation you should use a `newtype` instead.

Comment: Oh, by the way, you get `runArrayState` for free if you define `ArrayState` in this idiomatic style:  `newtype ArrayState arr e a = MkArrayState { runArrayState :: arr e -> (a, arr e) }`

Answer (score 3):

I think

```
runArrayState (MkArrayState act) arr = act arr
```

is what you are looking for.

Your type `ArrayState` is defined as having a single constructor `MkArrayState` that has its argument a function that takes arrays to pairs consisting of a result and (presumably) an updated array. In the definition above, we use the identifier `act` to refer to this function and `arr` to the array we have as an input. At the right-hand side of the definition, we then simply apply the function `act` to `arr` to obtain the required pair.

Alternatively, you can define your type as

```
data ArrayState arr e a = MkArrayState {runArrayState :: arr e -> (a, arr e)}
```

or, (most likely) better even,

```
newtype ArrayState arr e a = MkArrayState {runArrayState :: arr e -> (a, arr e)}
```

That way, you will have directly defined a destructor function of type `ArrayState arr e a -> arr e -> (a, arr e)` (i.e., without the class constraint, which is not required in the version above either).